# Why do JSON values not display in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am working PHP and MySQL. I am created a database and table. I want to convert table to JSON. So, I write this code block:

```
<?php

    include "../config/database.php";

        $SQLUser = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";  
        $SQLUserResult =mysqli_query($Conn,$SQLUser );
        $JSON= array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQLUserResult ))
        {
            $JSON[] = $row;
        }
        $Show =  json_encode($JSON);
        echo count($JSON);
        echo $Show;
?>
```

When run this page, I take JSON size correctly. But I can't display JSON values. What can I do?

In the page source, I see the count of rows in my JSON array (13), but no data.

Adding `var_dump($row);` shows me something like

```
array(13) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(1) "A" ["surname"]=> string(1) "A" } [1]=> array(3) { ...
```

The encoding is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Instead of your while loop, you could use `$JSON = mysqli_fetch_all($SQLUserResult);` to get all the rows. Furthermore I don't see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your database or tables returns probably a faulty response, some strings were probably not UTF-8. So, You can create a function for convert UTF-8.

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Than, you can encode just like this:

```
echo json_encode(utf8ize($JSON));
```

Comment: Also you can check your file encoding, should be UTF 8 w/o BOM